# Why when i logout in django after i updated my data appears this error?

Tags: python, django, django-views

i'm new in django and i'm trying to create an application that Admin have CRUD function. My problem is when admin updated other user, and then logged off, log off function worked properly. But, when admin updated him/her self then admin logout, appears this error

```
KeyError at /simofa/logout/
'username'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/simofa/logout/
Django Version: 1.7.4
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'username'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py in __delitem__, line 56
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/boss/kantor/akun',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
Server time:    Tue, 10 Mar 2015 02:24:44 +0000
```

This is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/simofa/logout/

Django Version: 1.7.4
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'simofa',
 'accounts')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/boss/kantor/akun/simofa/views.py" in logout
  174.     del request.session['username']
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in __delitem__
  56.         del self._session[key]

Exception Type: KeyError at /simofa/logout/
Exception Value: 'username'
```

This is my views: (update and logout)

```
def update_user(request, pk, template_name='update_user.html'):
    #cek session
    if 'username' in request.session:
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk) #ambil id dengan get
        profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=user).first()
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST, instance=user) #gunakan instance untuk mengambil data yang sudah ada
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=profile) #gunakan instance untuk mengambil data yang sudah ada
        users = User.objects.all()
        if request.POST:
            if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user.set_password(user.password) #hashing
                user.save()
                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user
                profile.save()
                return redirect('manajemen_user')
        else:
            user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
            profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

        data = {
                'user_form': user_form,
                'profile_form': profile_form,
                'object_list': users,
        }
        return render(request, template_name, data)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/simofa/login')

def logout(request):
    del request.session['username']
    del request.session['password']
    del request.session['hak_akses']
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/simofa/login')
```

I've confused with this error, why when admin update his self then logout it can't work properly? And how to fix it ?

Because i think nothing wrong with my update and logout function. 
I will very grateful for your input. So, please help me. Thank you very much

Comment: Try `request.session.modified = True` before the del commands. Could you tell me if that would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the user's password, [their session is reset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change). Django takes care of reinjecting the session hash so that the user isn't automatically logged out, but values you stored in the session will be gone.

I think you're trying to keep your logout view from crashing. In `logout`, change each line to look like this: `if 'username' in request.session: del request.session['username']` (replacing username with the correct value).

Comment: I tried in my project like in your reference link. But, it seems even make the user logged off automatically after updating their data. btw, thanks for your input sir :)

Comment: You asked why it wasn't working, but it sounds like what you really want to know is how to fix it  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes im sorry. Because your answers, I know where is my mistake. but I also want to know how to fix it sir :)

Comment: maybe you want to help me in my other question. please click here sir [How to re-input variable to session after update password in django ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957728/how-to-re-input-variable-to-session-after-update-password-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform `request.session.flush()`, so session data will be *flushed*, see [logout function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L89) from django auth source

```
def logout(request):
    """
    Removes the authenticated user's ID from the request and flushes their
    session data.
    """
    # Dispatch the signal before the user is logged out so the receivers have a
    # chance to find out *who* logged out.
    user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
    if hasattr(user, 'is_authenticated') and not user.is_authenticated():
        user = None
    user_logged_out.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)

    # remember language choice saved to session
    language = request.session.get(LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)

    request.session.flush()

    if language is not None:
        request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = language

    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
```