# How to re-input variable to session after update password in django ?

Tags: python, django, django-views

i'm new in django and i'm trying to create an application that Admin have CRUD function. My problem is when admin updated other user, it function work properly. But, when admin update him/her self, update function can not run properly. I know the problem located when i change the user's password, their session is reset. Django takes care of re-injecting the session hash so values stored in the session will be gone. So I want to ask, how to enter the value after i do an update my password to the session?

This is my views:

```
def update_user(request, pk, template_name='update_user.html'):
    #cek session
    if 'username' in request.session:
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk) #ambil id dengan get
        profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=user).first()
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST, instance=user) #gunakan instance untuk mengambil data yang sudah ada
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=profile) #gunakan instance untuk mengambil data yang sudah ada
        users = User.objects.all()
        if request.POST:
            if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user.set_password(user.password) #hashing
                user.save()
                # update_session_auth_hash(request, user_form.instance)
                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user
                profile.save()
                return redirect('manajemen_user')
        else:
            user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
            profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

        data = {
                'user_form': user_form,
                'profile_form': profile_form,
                'object_list': users,
        }
        return render(request, template_name, data)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/simofa/login')
```

I will very grateful for your input. So, please help me. Thank you very much :)

Comment: There's no reason for any of this. Changing a user's password does not affect their session in any way and there is no need to reset anything.

Comment: @Daniel, I may have steered ranggatry wrong in a prior question. I read the docs for [Session invalidation on password change](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change) to mean that the contents of the session are destroyed when you change the user's password. Incorrect?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : I have followed Matt Cooper to read that documentation. and I assume that when making changes the password, the session will be destroyed by itself. If you think not, why when I checked my session does not exist?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue... session variable are destroyed... Can you share with us how you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

#...
if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
  #...
  user = authenticate(username= user.username, user.password=password)
  login(request, user)
  #...
```

Uses authenticate, login within django.contrib.auth as above shown.

Comment: it's not about authenticate sir. It's about how to re-input value to the session when the old session destroyed by django. btw, thank you for your input sir :)